# How to add code to <head></head> in HTML with PHP and then display it?

Tags: php, head

I want to create a file (index.php) that will dynamically add the below code to the head of another file called (index2.php) and then display the page with the modified code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new.css">
<script src="new.js"></script>
<script>
new();
</script>
```

I know the way to do this without modifying the code is

```
include 'index2.php';
```

However I do not know how to add the code to the head section of index2.php

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just:

index2.php:

```php
...
<head>
<?php require("./index.php"); ?>
</head>
...
```

?

Comment: Yes, that is one way of doing it, however it is much more complicated and can't function that way.

Answer (score 0):

Put index2.php file's head tag code in a diffrent file. and then include that php file in index.php file's  tag
like
index.php
include_once('siffrent_file_name.php');
....

Answer (score 0):

After doing some pondering I felt like I didn't want to parse the entire HTML document, so I added a "key" to index2.php and used this code:

```
$file = "index2.php";
$key = "<!-- KEY -->";
$appcode = 'link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new.css">
<script src="new.js"></script>
<script>
new();
</script';

$index = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open index symlink");
$code= fread($index,filesize("index2.php"));
fclose($index);

$index_app = (preg_replace ($key, $appcode, $code));

echo($index_app);
```